# How to load a part of an webpage in android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I would like to make an app, that shows a part of the site.
Lets say that i have [this](http://www.hondsrugcollege.nl/leerlingen/leerlingrooster.html) site:

I only want to show this:
https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&ik=d5146163e8&view=att&th=132496ec47863fea&attid=0.1&disp=inline&realattid=f_gsbtyog80&zw
Is there anyway to do this?

I hope some of you could help me.

Gaauwe

Answer (score 1):

You could load the url to a WebView and then set the WebView's scroll position and zoom level to display only a specific part of the web page. If you don't want to change zoom level you could initially scroll the WebView to the required location and then override the WebView's onTouch method so that it will only scroll upto the required cordinates.

```
public class MyWebViewActivity extends Activity implements PictureListener{

private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setPictureListener(this);
        // disable scroll on touch
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
            }

        });
        webView.loadUrl(url);

    }


@Override
public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    webView.scrollTo(x, y);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to use PHP on your own server and CURL the webpage into it and strip out all the unnecessary things .

After that you only load it into your webview.
**This is one of the method,  there are others method better then this. **

Another way is coldfusion cfhttp .. not sure,about this http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_http.cfm